Spline Agent in AWS Glue
I have a glue job in AWS Glue that I'm trying to connect to my Spline server on EC2 using the spline agent jar, using the HTTP lineage dispatcher.
The glue logs show the correct producer url, and that the Spline is required and successfully initialises.
The Glue job at the moment just does a simple read operation (using spark.sql, from a data catalog in Glue) and writes to an s3 location (using df.write.parquet). The Glue job fails immediately after registering the Spline agent:
24/07/29 13:57:41 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Unknown error from Python: Error Traceback is not available.
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO ProcessLauncher: postprocessing
24/07/29 13:57:40 INFO SparkLineageInitializer: Spline Version: 2.0.0 (rev. 3eeab0b)
24/07/29 13:57:40 INFO SparkLineageInitializer: Init Type: AUTO (codeless)
24/07/29 13:57:40 INFO SparkLineageInitializer: Initializing Spline Agent...

The shutdown then continues with the following logs, including an uncaught error in some Java bits:
4/07/29 13:57:42 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.files.TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.createAndTrack(TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.java:125) ~[emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.54.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.files.TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.createTemporaryDirectories(TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.java:149) ~[emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.54.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:359) ~[emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.54.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1202) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1182) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1071) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:418) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:391) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2543) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2509) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2472) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-0.jar:?]
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(EmrFileSystem.java:512) ~[emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.54.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.LogPusher.upload(LogPusher.scala:72) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManagerWrapper$.$anonfun$addLogPusherHook$2(ShutdownHookManagerWrapper.scala:9) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManagerWrapper$.$anonfun$addLogPusherHook$2$adapted(ShutdownHookManagerWrapper.scala:9) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManagerWrapper$.$anonfun$addLogPusherHook$1(ShutdownHookManagerWrapper.scala:9) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2086) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:203) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.files.TemporaryDirectoryShutdownHook.<clinit>(TemporaryDirectoryShutdownHook.java:18) ~[emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.54.0.jar:?]
    ... 31 more
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO LogPusher: uploading /tmp/spark-event-logs/ to s3://aws-glue-assets-669523921719-eu-west-2/sparkHistoryLogs/
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO JESSchedulerBackend$JESAsSchedulerBackendEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO JESSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO ProcessLauncher: postprocessing finished
24/07/29 13:57:41 INFO LogPusher: stopping

I have set the Job parameters as follows:



Parameter
Value




--conf
spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields=1000 --conf spline.lineageDispatcher=http --conf spark.spline.producer.url=http://X.X.X.X:8080/producer --conf spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners=za.co.absa.spline.harvester.listener.SplineQueryExecutionListener --conf spark.spline.mode=REQUIRED


--packages
za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark:spark-3.3-spline-agent-bundle_2.12:2.0.0


--user-jars-first
true



And I have the following set in Dependant JARs path:
s3://redacted-s3-bucket-name/spline/spark-3.3-spline-agent-bundle_2.12-2.0.0.jar,s3://redacted-s3-bucket-name/spline/snakeyaml-2.2.jar
The Glue job is also on a VPC Connection on the same subnet as the Ec2. To ensure that the Glue job "sees" the EC2 server, I attempted to ping the spline producer API with a simple post request, and received the following response:
INFO GlueLogger: Required request body is missing: public scala.concurrent.Future<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> za.co.absa.spline.producer.rest.controller.v1.ExecutionEventsV1Controller.executionEvent(za.co.absa.spline.producer.model.ExecutionEvent[])

I assume this error stems from a badly made post body, but figured this is proof enough that basic networking is not the issue.
Any help would be appreciated, even just help in finding more useful log files than the ones that come in default for Glue 4.0

Which Glue version you are using? Glue 4.O is not supported with spline. Use Glue 3.O.
https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline-spark-agent#selecting-artifact
refer above given link to select spline spark agent (JAR) or you can directly download through
spark-3.1-spline-agent-bundle_2.12–0.6.1.jar
-------------- After EC2 servers setup for Spline -------------
Steps for Spline Integration with AWS Glue:
In Job details section -

Select IAM role and correct version of Glue.

IAM role and Spark version selection

Place the spline spark agent JAR file in s3 and add s3 path in dependent JARs path.

dependent JARs configs

Add job parameters.

Job parameters
Note: In job parameters "--conf" must be -
key:
--conf
value:
spark.spline.lineageDispatcher.http.producer.url=http://{EC2 instance IP}:8080/producer --conf spark.spline.mode=REQUIRED --conf spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners=za.co.absa.spline.harvester.listener.SplineQueryExecutionListener
Note: In above parameter, Replace {EC2 instance IP} with your actual EC2 instance IP.
